# Are the moon and the sun alive?

Tags: soul-eater

In Soul Eater, the sun and the moon seem to have a face and sometimes laugh.
Are they alive or is it just their design?

**The Sun and the Moon:**

[image]

Comment: there will probably be no evidence whatsoever to be found in the anime / manga... Maybe there is a word of god, and that's a big maybe, the rest will be speculations.

Comment: It's probably just a kind of visual gag only anime is capable of. Can't annoy readers enough with those laughing celestial bodies in manga :p

Comment: It's stated somewhere by the manga-ka that it is to symbolize the mood of the protagonist as in when they go into battle and/or the such.

Comment: the character do recognize the Sun at least. BlackStar at one point in the anime is mocking the Sun in the afternoon being unable to keep it's eyes open

Comment: Soul Eater Not! is airing right now and we see the characters from Soul Eater there (including the two guys in question), so maybe this time there'll be a definite answer.

Comment: Soul Eater Not is more of a side dish so I doubt they will ever go into the sun/moon thing.

Comment: Can confirm Soul Eater Not didn't discuss this at all, at least the animated version

Answer (score 9):

A somewhat theoretical answer:

Living things display the *7 characteristics of life* - which are:

- Movement
- Respiration
- Sensitivity
- Growth
- Reproduction
- Excretion
- Nutrition

They definetly exhibit movement and respiration
[image]

And they are sensitive to conditions of the atmosphere
[image]

They do not appear to grow, but this could be because they are adult.

They do not appear to reproduce.

They excrete light onto the world.

The moon *may* be eating something.

[image]

If the sun and moon's reproduction properties are anything like our own, which they are modelled off, they are non-existant. Stars and planets are *formed* - a non-biological formation without passing on any genetic information

This, combined with the fact that many of the other characteristics are assuming a lot, can bring us to the conclusion that they are not living,

Although, having said that, there are a couple rare articles around the web that claim stars are living. [Example](http://www.starlarvae.org/Star_Larvae_The_Stellar_Organism.html)

So I guess you can justify it to be either true or false, whichever you would prefer :)

Comment: Stars are poop?

Comment: plants don't poop and they're alive

Comment: If you think of a lost petal as their excrement then... it would?

Comment: many character on anime didn't show Growth, Reproduction, Excretion, or Nutrition, but they're alive. They're usually either gods or mythical beast.

Comment: Plants excrete oxygen guys... Not poop!